# mysql: SUM 3 records per category

Tags: mysql, sql, select, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with the following columns:

```
dayoftheweek (VARCHAR)
player (VARCHAR)
score (INT)
```

For each player, there are either 3, 4 or 5 scores.
I have to calculate the average of the best 3 scores for each player per dayoftheweek.

I was thinking along the lines of

```
SELECT dayoftheweek, player, (SUM(score) / 3) AS average_score
FROM (SELECT dayoftheweek, player, score
      FROM scoretable
      GROUP BY dayoftheweek, player
      ORDER BY score
      LIMIT 0, 3) AS query
```

But (obviously) that only gives me the first three records overall..
Can someone put me in the right direction please?

Cheers, Marcel

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to write:

```
SELECT dayoftheweek,
       player,
       ( SELECT AVG(score)
           FROM ( SELECT inner.score
                    FROM scoretable AS inner
                   WHERE inner.dayoftheweek = outer.dayoftheweek
                    AND inner.player = outer.player
                   ORDER
                      BY inner.score DESC
                   LIMIT 3
                )
       ) AS best_score_avg
  FROM scoretable AS outer
;
```

(Disclaimer: not tested.)

Note that I used `ORDER BY ... DESC` to get the three *greatest* scores, but if these are golf scores or something where the best scores are the *least* ones, then you'll want to change `DESC` to `ASC` (or just remove it).